# Which reducers should be in react-boilerplate's reducers.js?

Tags: reactjs, reducers, react-boilerplate

It says in the `createReducer` function of [`reducers.js`](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/reducers.js) that it creates the main reducer with the asynchronously loaded ones:

```
/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the asynchronously loaded ones
 */
export default function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    global: globalReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ...asyncReducers,
  });
}
```

When you generate a route, the reducers are injected there. So which reducers should be in `reducers.js`? What exactly are `async reducers`?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the dynamically injected ones
 */
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    global: `globalReducer`,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  });
```

I think. Its an injectedReducer rather than asyncReducer. You can used this to inject reducers dynamically at runtime inside your components index file as shown in the boileplate example.